# How to call a client side javascript function after a specific UpdatePanel has been loaded

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, updatepanel

### How is it possible to call a client side javascript method after a *specific* update panel has been loaded?

**`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler)`** does not work for me because this will fire after ANY update panel finishes loading, and I can find no client side way to find which is the one

**`ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackSourceElementID AsyncPostBackSourceElementID`** does not work for me as this is a server side object, and i want Client Side

The ClientSide .Net framework must know which UpdatePanel it is updating in order to update the correct content.  Surely there is a way to hook into this event?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can hook the [PageRequestManager.beginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) event and inspect the [BeginRequestEventArgs.postBackElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397485.aspx) property.

Note that it doesn't *really* give you the UpdatePanel, but the control inside of the UpdatePanel. That should be good enough, though.

Edit: Even better, the [PageRequestManager.pageLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx) event gives you [PageLoadedEventArgs.panelsUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384016.aspx) (and [panelsCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397552.aspx)) properties.

Answer (score 48):

Thanks - both good answers. I went with the client side script "pageloaded" in the end.  That is a fairly buried method that google did not reveal to me.  For those who are interested, this code works with FireBug to give a good demo of the PageLoaded method working to find the updated panels:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            panelsLoaded = 1;
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded)
        });

        function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
            console.log("I have occured " + panelsLoaded++ + " times!");

            var panelsCreated = args.get_panelsCreated();
            for (var i = 0; i < panelsCreated.length; i++) {
                console.log("Panels Updating: " + panelsCreated[i].id);
            }

            var panelsUpdated = args.get_panelsUpdated();
            for (var i = 0; i < panelsUpdated.length; i++) {
                console.log("Panels Updating: " + panelsUpdated[i].id);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: For some reason the add_pageLoaded method doesn't exist for me... :(

Comment: Great solution, I've been searching for answers to this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

This may be your solution.

In the code behind for the UpdatePanel's OnLoad event, register a startup script.

```
string scriptText = "alert('Bar!');";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "foo", scriptText, true);
```