# Modifying dropdownlist inside jquery popup affects after re-opening popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, updatepanel, postback

I have a dropdownlist, which with its selectedindexchanged event it populates a second dropdownlist. they are hosted in a jquery popup and they are all parts of a user control which all of its contenttemplate is surrounded with an updatepanel.

My problem is that population of the second dropdownlist is happened after closing and re-opening the popup.

Can you please guide me on what can be the source of the problem?

Comment: Can you put the UpdatePanel inside the jQuery popup?

Comment: I tested it with keeping the parent updatepanel for the whole control and adding a child one just for the popup but it did not help.

Comment: I think the issue is that the HTML contents of the UpdatePanel are reloaded when the second dropdownlist is loaded.  If the default state of the popup is "closed", you will have to re-open once the UpdatePanel is reloaded - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190549/how-can-i-run-some-javascript-after-an-update-panel-refreshes