# jQuery event to catch loaded content

Tags: jquery, events

I have aspx page with form which fire result to div on the same page. I need to process hrefs inside result output. Which action should be used in this case? `$(document).ready` and `$(document).ajaxComplete` didn't work. Concerning `ajaxComplete` as I understand it is because not a jQuery routine is used by page controls.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('a[href*="mouz"]').removeAttr('href');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For load event, try this $(window).load(function(){ ... });

Comment: If I undertand you well, you want when you click an `a` link you put the result in a `div` by an `Ajax` call?

Comment: when you say "aspx page with form which fire result to div", what do you mean? what exactly is triggering this? update panel?

Comment: @attila yes, update panel.

Comment: this appears to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190549/how-can-i-run-some-javascript-after-an-update-panel-refreshes

Comment: Show us the code that is loading the dynamic content.  We need to see that in order to know how to advise you how to wait for it.

Comment: @attila `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);` solved, thanks. If you post as answer I will accept :)

Comment: @revoua - glad it helped. I have added as answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, adapted from MSDN - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In your client script add the following

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
```

to handle the event,

```
function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
  //get all of the panels which have been updated
  var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated(); 

  //perform the removal of the href attr on the DOM element collection
  $(updatedPanels).find('a[href*="mouz"]').removeAttr('href');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
// executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
alert("window is loaded");
});
</script>
```