# Response.Redirect not working when using UpdateProgress

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, response.redirect, updateprogress

I use an UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress.

Both `Response.Redirect` and `JavaScript redirect window` not working with them.

This code is working:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true"
        AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="ImageWait" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/wait.gif" />
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save"
        OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" ValidationGroup="Valid1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonSave"
            EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Not working :

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Saved here

    Response.Redirect("../Main/Success.aspx");
}
```

Not working, too :

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Saved here

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect",
        "location.href = '../Main/Success.aspx'", true);
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: if you put a break point in the event handler does it reach it?
I am guessing, not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run some javascript after an update panel refreshes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190549/how-can-i-run-some-javascript-after-an-update-panel-refreshes)

Comment: @DaniDev yes, the compiler reaches the button line but the redirect not executed

Comment: Async calls with redirects are not a good/safe practice because you are creating another thread which will be left orphaned when redirecting. 
If you are going redirect you don't need to create a trigger for it since it will not be updating the form. I recommend you just do a simple postback

Comment: @DaniDev, okey thanks, so you say, async. calls may cause to injection, is it right?

Comment: @DaniDev, how can I do a simple postback? If I refresh the same page, it does not work, too.

Comment: a simple postback means that you user the event handler ("ButtonSave_Click") as you are and just remove the async trigger (the trigger is used to tell the form that it needs to update the Update Panel. BUT you are not updating the form, as you are redirecting.

Comment: You have already accepted an answer but I am concerned that you are creating a problem for yourself which will manifest when you introduce this into production. If you wish I will post an answer which describes and explains what I am saying

Comment: Yes I wanted to use a more secure way. I will ask a new question

Comment: You don't really need a new question. I can just post an answer here if you like.
Basically you just need to remove the Trigger and either one of your options above should work.

Comment: Yes please. It would be great

Comment: where are the contents/ input controls that you are saving.
Are there any other controls/triggers that trigger the Ajax functionality for your UpdatePanel ?

Comment: but they are so long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ScriptManager`

```
protected void redirector_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "redirect",
        "location.href = 'ListViewDemo.aspx';", true);
}
```

Comment: I had to change it to ScriptManager1, then it gets error with RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: ScriptManager is the class not the instance

Comment: Ok - it says, the name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context. How can I define ScriptManager in code behind?

Comment: try `using System.Web.UI;`