# executing one line of javascript on asynchronous ajax event in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, elasticlayout

I am using the Elastic CSS framework on an ASP.NET site. It is doing a great job of sizing the various containers I have until an UpdatePanel executes a partial postback. The solution as I understand it is to execute the following line of javascript

```
Elastic.refresh();
```

I'm pretty good with C# and ASP.NET but not so much with javascript. As I understand it, RegisterStartupScript only registers the script, I still need a control to then execute it.

So how can I get this one line of javascript to execute when a custom control catches a custom exception and causes a partial postback?

Comment: I may have made a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338702/how-to-call-a-client-side-javascript-function-after-a-specific-updatepanel-has-be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

In javascript on your page you could also try something like this

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoadedHandler);
function PageLoadHandler()
{
    Elastic.refresh();
}
```

This handler will run after any callback but `sender._postBackSettings.panelID` will allow you to filter it to the panel you want.

Alternativly you could try if end request fits your needs better.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function PageLoadHandler()
{
    Elastic.refresh();
}
```

**Original**

Do you have a ScriptManager control on the page that has the UpdatePanel? If so you might be able to leverage the ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackError and have it execute your method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerror.aspx

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure exactly how that would be used.

Comment: When I read "when a custom control catches a custom exception and causes a partial" I thought you were saying that an error was thrown during the async postback. Now that I look at it again, I'm guess this isn't the case. :)

Comment: correct. I have one custom control raising an event which the containing page then catches. That event is registered as a trigger for an asynchronous event. At the end of that event I need that one line of javascript to run.

Comment: @Justin I've updated my answer. Hopefully this one is more useful than the original.

Comment: Thank you so much, your post combined with my comment above about this potentially being a duplicate put it all together. FWIW I think you need to use pageLoad instead of PageLoadHandler. Not sure why that would matter but it seemed to. I ended up going with the end handler though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but I'd try using a literal control w/in the ajax panel that contained the following:

```
<script language="javascript">
Elastic.refresh();
</script>
```

If I'm right the Ajax panel will reload and that will automatically execute that line of code when it does.

Comment: Nice idea but doesn't seem to work, tried putting it at various levels of the page and containers.